# How we can differentiat backbone.js collection and models, and what can be embed in view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

In a backbone.js app how collection and model differentiat and can we render collection using view?(if yes, then what is best practice))

Comment: Please try and explain what you are trying to do I don't think anyone understands what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

[Responsibilities of variance Backbone components](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/27/the-responsibilities-of-the-various-pieces-of-backbone-js/)

The views/layouts and their hierarchy:

http://artandlogic.com/2013/03/a-visual-guide-to-marionette-js-views/

Backbone Event lifecycle:

http://benmccormick.org/2015/01/05/marionette-view-life-cycles/